Could not add feature with geometry type GeometryCollection to layer of type MultiPolygon
I have a polygon layer and I joined a few attributes via csv. On this joined layer, I run a graphical modeler 'model'. This model has a dissolve tool. The model works as expected. Now I wanted to make this join (via csv) to become permanent shapefile. So I right click and Export>Save Features as> "new_name.shp"
When I load this new_name.shp, and then run the same graphical modeler model, I get an error as below.

Feature could not be written to Dissolved_c7a5d973_9692_41bf_b801_d41bbfcdf8d8: Could not add feature with geometry type GeometryCollection to layer of type MultiPolygon
Error encountered while running 1 Dissolve: Could not write feature into OUTPUT
Execution failed after 0.63 seconds


I checked geometry of my new_name.shp with 'geom_to_wkt( @geometry )' and all are multipolygon.
I tried fix-geometries, and I have no error in geometries.
I tried v.clean to find any errors. I get no errors.

I do not understand this line 'Could not add feature with geometry type GeometryCollection to layer of type MultiPolygon'
What could be wrong and how to solve this?

Maybe try check validity before fix geometrIes to see if there are any problem spots and fix manually?

Save the result into some format that allows mixed geometry types. For example GeoPackage with a non-constrained geometry type "geometry". Then you can check if the result really contains geometry collections, and analyze where they come.

Do I understand right that you have have already a) joined the new attributes from the CSV file and b) dissolved the geometries and c) saved the result successfully into shapefile "new_name.shp"? Why do you want to run the model again? For joining more attributes to "new_name", or to dissolve by some other attribute, or what? Of have I understood something wrong?

@user30184.  I joined attributes from csv, checked my model. everythings works as expected. For model to work, I need to join attributes. In order to run the model in future I need a file with those csv attributes. Since the join is temporary, I make it permanent with export. Ideally i would expect the model to work on this permanent join as it works on a tempoary in session join.

So the "new_name" shapefile has the original geometries with some additional attributes, not dissolved geometries? In that case it feels that some geometries in the "new_name" changed from the original. You can test that theory by running difference between the original geometries and the geometries in the "new_name". Attribute join should not affect geometries and the difference should be null. If that is not the case, compare the original geometries with the geometries in "new_name" and study what has changed.

indeed the difference is not null. there are hundreds of small silvers.

I would expect dissolve to return a GeometryCollection because it can return points and lines as well as Polygons. You can't add a GeometryCollection to a (Multi)Polygon shapefile as it can only have one type of geometry per file (and it will never accept a GeometryCollection).
So you need to extract (just) the (Multi)Polygons from the collection that you have, I'm not sure if there is an easy way to do that from the GUI but this question gives some python code to do it.

thanks @Ian, but then its puzzling  why is the model working in a qgis session with temporary join of csv and not with permanent join (exported shp i mean)

because a joined csv doesn't care about geometry type but  a shapefile does
